# And Engine background image

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

Recently I started working on AndEngine.

I am trying to set a background image of my scene.

But for some reason the background image is not filling the screen completely.

Any Suggestion and Help ?

Here is my source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

Scene sc;

protected final static int cam_wid = 320;

protected final static int cam_heigh = 456;

BitmapTextureAtlas texAtlas;

    ITextureRegion texRegion;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera ca = new Camera(0, 0, cam_wid, cam_heigh);
        EngineOptions en = new EngineOptions(true,
                ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                        cam_wid, cam_heigh), ca);
        return en;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        load();
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    private void load() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        texAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 512);
        texRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                texAtlas, this, "imagery.png", 0, 0);
        texAtlas.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.sc = new Scene();
        Sprite s = new Sprite(0, 0, cam_wid, cam_heigh, texRegion,
                this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        SpriteBackground sb = new SpriteBackground(s);
        sc.setBackground(sb);
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(sc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the device width and height like  below and use it

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
cam_wid =dm.widthPixels;
cam_heigh =dm.heightPixels;
```

The other thing Your background picture may be smaller (less height) than your screen.
So either you scale your picture or you make is repeat. In the last case you can set the texture atlas to `TextureOptions.REPEATING_BILINEAR` and then make you sprite bigger.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out the problem.I tried adjusting the values of width and height of my image according to that of my phone.

Comment: @user3624963 please use my code for camera width  and height

Comment: @user3624963 and whats your image diemensions ?

Comment: width=256 and height=512